# Cannot get selected font to work

Tags: fonts

Im trying to get a custom font to work, but with no succes.
`fc-list` shows that they are installed, but `XeLaTeX` does not compile the file.

```
stefandekraker ~ % fc-list | grep "Cabinet Grotesk"
/Users/stefandekraker/Library/Fonts/CabinetGrotesk-Extrabold.otf: Cabinet Grotesk,Cabinet Grotesk Extrabold:style=Extrabold,Regular
/Users/stefandekraker/Library/Fonts/CabinetGrotesk-Thin.otf: Cabinet Grotesk,Cabinet Grotesk Thin:style=Thin,Regular
/Users/stefandekraker/Library/Fonts/CabinetGrotesk-Medium.otf: Cabinet Grotesk,Cabinet Grotesk Medium:style=Medium,Regular
```

I would like to use the `Cabinet Grotesk Thin` style.

```latex
\setmainfont{Rubik}

\addtokomafont{section}{\LARGE \fontspec{Cabinet Grotesk Thin}\color{Midnight}}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\Large \fontspec{Cabinet Grotesk Thin}\color{Midnight}}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\large \fontspec{Cabinet Grotesk Thin}\color{Midnight}}
```

But I keep getting:

```
Package fontspec Error: The font "Cabinet Grotesk Thin" cannot be
(fontspec)                found.
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper, top=1in, bottom=1.75in, left=1in, right=1.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
% Setup the custom fonts for the headers and the text itself

\setmainfont{Rubik}

\addtokomafont{section}{\LARGE \fontspec{Cabinet Grotesk Thin}}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\Large \fontspec{Cabinet Grotesk Thin}}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\large \fontspec{Cabinet Grotesk Thin}}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\fontspec{Rubik}}
\addtokomafont{sectionentry}{\fontspec{Rubik}}

\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    Some text for testing the fonts of the document

\end{document}
```

**Update**:

`\newfontface{\cabinet}{CabinetGrotesk-Thin}` trows this error:
[image]

Comment: As always on the site, please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Also note that XeLaTeX is very sensitive as to where it looks for fonts. It might be an idea to use lualatex instead.

Comment: try `CabinetGrotesk-Thin.otf` rather than `Cabinet Grotesk Thin` (although both should work if fontconfig sees it)

Comment: What does `otfinfo -p ~/Library/Fonts/CabinetGrotesk-Thin.otf` output?

Comment: @egreg `otfinfo -p ~/Library/Fonts/CabinetGrotesk-Thin.otf` returns: 
`CabinetGrotesk-Thin`

Comment: @daleif I added some more code to the question

Comment: You should make it a single minimal example, not several files containing stuff that are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I guess that `\newfontface{\cabinet}{CabinetGrotesk-Thin}` and `\addtokomafont{section}{\LARGE\cabinet}` should work. Never use `\fontspec` in a working document.

Comment: @egreg see my updated post please

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by including the fonts a folder `fonts` in the root directory of the project.
And adding a absolute path to the folder with the help of the `Path` parameter of the `\setmainfont` command.

```latex
\setmainfont[Path=<Absolute_path>/fonts/]{Rubik-Light.ttf}[
    BoldFont       = Rubik-Medium.ttf,
    ItalicFont     = Rubik-LightItalic.ttf,
    BoldItalicFont = Rubik-MediumItalic.ttf]
```